# ImportError: No module named 'theano.floatX'

Tags: theano, deep-learning

I am following a tutorial to create [convolution neural network with Theano](http://deeplearning.net/tutorial/lenet.html#lenet). Although, I got a problem in a piece of code:

```
>> x = theano.floatX.xmatrix(theano.config.floatX)  # rasterized images
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'floatX'
```

I loaded floatX with:

```
>> from theano import config
```

and checked with:

```
>> print(theano.config.floatX)
float 32
```

But still cannot load the module `xmatrix`, which should be in `theano.config.floatX`, judging from [documentation](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/floatX.html). Does somebody know where can I find it?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

This sections of the convnet tutorial has a bug or is very outdated. Symbolic variables in Theano are located in theano.tensor package. This package theano.floatX even doesn't exist!

The current version in the tutorial github repository works fine. They allocate the symbolic variable the right way:

```
# allocate symbolic variables for the data
    index = T.lscalar()  # index to a [mini]batch
    x = T.matrix('x')   # the data is presented as rasterized images
    y = T.ivector('y')  # the labels are presented as 1D vector of
                        # [int] labels
```

Browsing the tutorial repository I found the [revision where this bug was corrected](https://github.com/lisa-lab/DeepLearningTutorials/commit/21065c8271913be6667357cbd3df5d37bba144d1). 
They seem to have forgotten to update the tutorial text with this fix.

Comment: This is the right answer. I just pushed a fix to the repository. The web page should be updated in the next hour. This was a bug, theano.floatX never existed.